# Air France claim: asked for passport & other passenger's bank info

Tags: compensation, air-france

Our Air France flight Paris → Los Angeles had to land in Las Vegas due to technical issues. To get home we had to rent a car and drive for 4 hours. Other option was to spend night in LV or get on a bus promised by AF.

We filed a compensation claim and now AF is asking for my bank info and for my spouse's bank info and passport scans. The email is sent from seemingly legit customercare@infos-airfrance.com. Is that normal?

> Dear Mr.___,   Thank you for ypur (*sic!*) reply.   As per our record,the
> details for the other passenger on the reservation are not provided.
> In this case,I kindly ask you to send the mentioned details for the
> other passenger.   Bank details have to be personal for the other
> passenger on the file.   Also,the passport image of each passenger are
> required for us to proceed.   Looking forward for your reply.
>
> Best regards, Daniel Behari Air France and KLM Customer Care Assistant

Comment: It is normal to ask for your bank information in order to, well, transfer the money to you.

Comment: The usual advice when you are not sure about the provenance of an email you received: Call/email the company back, and ask them if they sent this. In my limited infosec experience, addresses like "infos-airfrance.com" are often *not* legit. Anyone could have bought that address. But sometimes it is just the IT guys being lazy or some silly bureaucracy preventing them from using an @airfrance.fr address.

Comment: I'd suggest you follow @user253751 recommandation, a very fast lookup of the site indicates that it would be a genuine AF site. But, email spoof is soo easy and the word *kindly* being nearly always a red flag when regarding scams, better shield yourself

Comment: ‘Send the mentioned details’ and ‘looking forward *for*’ sound odd to me. Follow @user253751’s recommendation and verify the email via an independent means

Comment: Doesn't seem odd to me.  The customer service representative is likely not a native English speaker.  To me it would seem legitimate.

Comment: @gerrit: in the email there is nothing specific about the case, so it should be a template. And asking passport image is a clear sign of a scam. On all compensation I never ever been asked a document.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I agree that asking for the passport image is a red flag for a bank transfer.  I had overlooked this.

Comment: Hover over the email link (customer care at…) and see if it actually directs to that address or not. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Air France’s website, this appears to be a scam. Reason: “asks for proof of identity or bank details”

On the list that they use is customer-care (with a hyphen) at airfrance dot fr. Also says they use at infos-airfrance dot com

If there is nothing specific about the booking (REF # abc123) then it’s a scam. “This type of email will always contain information that you recognize, like your booking reference while your Flying Blue number”

So the domain *seems* legit. But that is what is in the text. It might actually direct to another address. So:

Hover over the part of the email that says where to send the info. See if it actually directs to that address. Look carefully- it could be off by just one letter. (0r a character that looks similar h/t to @PeterM)

See here:
https://wwws.airfrance.fr/en/information/legal/edito-phishing

Comment: It's not just one letter off that can be the issue.  It could be a letter that looks correct, but is in fact another letter that looks similar in unicode.

Comment: @PeterM great point